# Twitter OAuth signing process explanation

Tags: oauth, twitter

I was going through this process https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens and there are two points that do not make clear sense to me:

1. Step 1: **POST OAuth/request_token**

response includes *oauth_token_secret*. What is the purpose of this value? It is not mentioned anywhere later in the process. The only mention of this in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-2.1 is in section 2.1:

```
oauth_token_secret
         The temporary credentials shared-secret.
```

2. *oauth_token* throughout the process.

Again, in STEP 1. there is written

```
Your app should verify that oauth_callback_confirmed is true and store the other two values for the next steps.
```

'The other two values' meaning oauth_token and oauth_token_secret. The oauth_token is then again returned in STEP 2. (after successful authorization on the Twitter page), and then used in STEP 3.
What is the purpose of storing it in STEP 1. instead of just using the value returned in STEP 2. Can these two differ in some cases?

Comment: I think this answer on stack overflow already answers this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993591/1539816

Comment: The first point is kind of explained in answer from mulllhausen, and that it is a bug on twitter side. The second point about a need for storing the oauth_token is not